# Payu is not working in WKWebview objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, payumoney, payu

I am trying to use PayU in WKWebiew , After filling all the credentials related to payment when I click on pay now button, nothing happens except  loading

```
-(void)setupWebVw : (NSString*)url{

    netConnAvailable = [[AppDelegate getdelegate] checkInternetConn];
    if(netConnAvailable){

        self.wkWebView.hidden = NO;
        NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
        [_wkWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [_wkWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
        fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl];
        self.networkErrorVw.hidden = YES;

    }else{

        self.wkWebView.hidden = YES;
        self.networkErrorVw.hidden = NO;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details to your question, for instance, here's the code for the Pay Now button?

Comment: Have you verified this works in a HTTP client such as Postman?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved the issue